# Show a chart based on a condition

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code, where you can enter a string, click a button and get a result depending on the string entered:

```
# ui.R

ui <- fluidPage(
    conditionalPanel(
        "input.btn_input === 0",
        textInput("caption", "Caption", "abc"),
        actionButton("btn_input", "Enter")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
        "input.btn_input !== 0",
        style = "display: none;",
        verbatimTextOutput("value")
    )
)

# server.R

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    Response <- eventReactive(input$btn_input, {
        v <- input$caption
        if (v == "xxx") {
            # Allow to use the chart
        } else {
            "Error"
        }
    })
    
    output$value <- renderPrint({
        Response()
    })
}
```

Now, instead of `# Allow to use the chart` I want to insert the chart contained in the Shiny example, that is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do it? The best I have been able to do is show the sidebar panel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `shinyjs` package to show and hide elements based on conditions.

For example, we can wrap the `sidebarLayout` with a `div` to give it a unique id parameter. Here's an example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  #initialize shinyjs
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  textInput("caption", "Caption", "abc"),
  hidden(verbatimTextOutput("value")),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(
    id = "sidebar_part",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
          "Number of bins:",
          min = 1,
          max = 50,
          value = 30
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # condition to show the sidebarLayout
  observeEvent(input$caption,
    {
      if (input$caption == "xxx") {
        shinyjs::hide("caption")
        shinyjs::show("sidebar_part")
        shinyjs::hide("value")
      } else {
        shinyjs::show("value")
        output$value <- renderText({
          "error"
        })
      }
    },
    ignoreInit = TRUE
  )

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "darkgray", border = "white")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

## Edit:

Using an `actionButton` and hiding everything except the error when the incorrect answer is provided.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  # initialize shinyjs
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  div(
    id = "caption_and_send",
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "abc"),
    actionButton("send", "Send")
  ),
  hidden(verbatimTextOutput("value")),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(
    id = "sidebar_part",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
          "Number of bins:",
          min = 1,
          max = 50,
          value = 30
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # condition to show the sidebarLayout
  observeEvent(input$send,
    {
      if (input$caption == "xxx") {
        shinyjs::hide("caption_and_send")
        shinyjs::show("sidebar_part")
      } else {
        shinyjs::hide("caption_and_send")
        shinyjs::show("value")
        output$value <- renderText({
          "error"
        })
      }
    },
    ignoreInit = TRUE
  )

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "darkgray", border = "white")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I wanted, as in my example, to have a button that if clicked shows either the graph or the error message (thus hiding both the input text and the button itself)?

Comment: @LJG I edited my answer to add a button and hide everything except the error message.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Maybe it is better to include `shinyjs::hide("caption_and_send")` even in the `if (input$caption == "xxx") { ... }` and not only in the `else { ... }`.

Comment: Why did you remove also `shinyjs::hide("value")` in the if clause? I mean, it works either way, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Because `hidden(verbatimTextOutput("value"))` is initialized as a hidden input, so if the text is correct, the app will display the sidebarLayout directly with no need to hide the 'value' input because it is already hidden from the start. On the other hand, the app now shows an error instead of letting the user retry to enter the correct characters.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Just a curiosity: is there a way to hide `titlePanel` once the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way would be to wrap titlePanel element with a div and give it and id parameter.  `div(id = 'myid', titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"))` and hide it when the correct string is entered like we did with the other elements.